# Ruby on Rails 4. Uni-directional associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to solve two tasks in my rails app and i need some advice:

1. I have Person model and Car Model. One person can have only one car. it means that Car always has driver = person, but not each person has a car. So i need uni-directional One to One here. Is it possible to implement with rails? Actually i need has_one on Car and i don't need belongs_to on Person
2. I have Order and Load models. In my system there are many orders and when i am ready to deliver these orders I construct new Load object and put all orders which i want to deliver there. So every Load has_many orders but not each order belongs_to Load. It is uni-directional one-to-many... Also i don't need something like `order.load,` i need only `load.orders`

So how can I implement it with rails?

Comment: Why we don't need belongs_to here, just define it, because if 'car.person == nil' that means car doesn't belong to any person, else car belongs to a person. That totally makes sense, right?

Comment: You are right, then I don't need to use has_one? Because there can be a case when person has no car?

Comment: You still need has_one, because person.car == nil, that means that person has no car. That is normal :) make it easy. has_one/belongs_to here means: a person may have 1/0 car, and a car may belong to 1/0 person. That is actually 1-1 relation

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :car
end

class Load < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

Then you can call person_instance.car or load_instance.orders.  You will have to have load_id on the orders and person_id on the cars